# Facebook 'Sorry something went wrong' swift

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook, facebook-login

I have previously been logged on to the iOS Simulator on xcode using Facebook, but logged out to login with another test user. After logging in I receive the message below. Given I've been logged on before I don't think this should be a permission issue which I've seen on similar posts - my app is live on facebook developer.

The latest post from this issue is 2015 so if any updated experience on this problem would be appreciated.

[image]

Code

View Controller

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    let loginButton = FBLoginButton()
    loginButton.center = view.center
    loginButton.permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "id", "name"]
    loginButton.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
     }

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: 
LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {

    if AccessToken.current != nil {
       print("logged in")
       let tabBar = TabBarController()
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBar, animated: true)
    }
    else {
       print("not logged in")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved, had added extra permissions, only worked when asked for public_profile and emial

```
  loginButton.permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
```